# [ERROR] No p gain specified for pid

Tags: ros, pid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I working on writing my own PID controller for my project. When I try to launch my controllers I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1360377867.632497162]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /l_arm_controller/pid_parameters
[ERROR] [1360377867.632712020]: LeftArmController could not construct PID controller for joint 'base_to_left_shoulder'
[ERROR] [1360377867.632769857]: Initializing controller 'l_arm_controller' failed
```

It says I don't have any p gain specified but here is my .yaml file:

```
l_arm_controller:
  type: my_controller_pkg/LeftArmControllerPlugin
  left_shoulder_link: base_to_left_shoulder
  left_tricep_link: left_rotator_to_tricep
  left_lower_bicep_link: left_upper_to_lower_bicep
  left_upper_forearm_link: left_lower_bicep_to_upper_forearm
  left_wrist_link: left_lower_forearm_to_wrist
  left_hand_link: left_wrist_to_hand
pid_parameters:
  p: 150.0
  i: 0.0
  d: 0.0
  i_clamp: 0.0

r_arm_controller:
  type: my_controller_pkg/RightArmControllerPlugin
  right_shoulder_link: base_to_right_shoulder
  right_tricep_link: right_rotator_to_tricep
  right_lower_bicep_link: right_upper_to_lower_bicep
  right_upper_forearm_link: right_lower_bicep_to_upper_forearm
  right_wrist_link: right_lower_forearm_to_wrist
  right_hand_link: right_wrist_to_hand
pid_parameters:
  p: 150.0
  i: 0.0
  d: 0.0
  i_clamp: 0.0
```

The pid values are just the test values from the tutorial to see if I can launch the controllers but unfortunately they don't launch. Does any one know where this error comes from?

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54789/%5Berror%5D-no-p-gain-specified-for-pid./) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the indentation in that yaml file, it looks neither set of `pid_parameters` is under `X_arm_controller` they're both in the parent namespace.

You'd need to indent the `pid_parameters` block by two more spaces like (spaces replaced with `.` for clarity):

```
l_arm_controller:
..type: my_controller_pkg/LeftArmControllerPlugin
..left_shoulder_link: base_to_left_shoulder
..left_tricep_link: left_rotator_to_tricep
..left_lower_bicep_link: left_upper_to_lower_bicep
..left_upper_forearm_link: left_lower_bicep_to_upper_forearm
..left_wrist_link: left_lower_forearm_to_wrist
..left_hand_link: left_wrist_to_hand
..pid_parameters:
....p: 150.0
....i: 0.0
....d: 0.0
....i_clamp: 0.0
```

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-09**:
Oh man, I did not even know that! I'm still learning a lot of new programming :) Thank you very much for the response